# Setting variables in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to define variables before a CTE table and after a CTE table because some variables are dependent on the result of the CTE table. For example

```
SET(K,B) = (5,2);

with my_data(Key,Index,Value) as (
    -- data table as cte
    select * from values
        (1, 3, 10),
        (1, 5, 18),
        (1, 14, 4),
        (2, 2, 11),
        (2, 13, 24),
        (2, 29, 40)
)

SELECT VALUE + $K
FROM my_data
```

This examples works perfectly. But this code:

```
SET(K,B) = (5,2);

with my_data(Key,Index,Value)   as (
    -- data table as cte
    select * from values
        (1, 3, 10 ),
        (1, 5, 18 ),
        (1, 14, 4 ),
        (2, 2, 11 ),
        (2, 13, 24),
        (2, 29, 40)
)

SET AVG_VAL = (SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM my_data);

SELECT VALUE + $AVG_VAL
FROM my_data
```

doesn't because snowflake gives me this error

> "SQL compilation error: syntax error line 34 at position 0 unexpected 'SET'."

Should I create a temporary table to store the result of this query `(SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM my_data)` in it and then include/use this temporary table for future queries instead of a variable?

Comment: Please put variable in brackets - set (var) = (query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "CTE" is not a standalone "thing" it only exist in the context of a SELECT.

Thus

```
WITH cte_x AS (...)
SELECT * FROM cte_x
```

is one SELECT which has a CTE attached to it.

Thus for you variable assignment the CTE has to be "IN" the paren's

```
   with my_data(Key,Index,Value) as (
        select * from values
            (1, 3, 10 ),
            (1, 5, 18 ),
            (1, 14, 4 ),
            (2, 2, 11 ),
            (2, 13, 24),
            (2, 29, 40)
    )
    SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM my_data;
```

| AVG(VALUE) |
| --- |
| 17.833333 |

given that is a discrete chunk of SQL, that can be captured into the variable:

```
set AVG_VAL = (
    with my_data(Key,Index,Value) as (
        select * from values
            (1, 3, 10 ),
            (1, 5, 18 ),
            (1, 14, 4 ),
            (2, 2, 11 ),
            (2, 13, 24),
            (2, 29, 40)
    )
    SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM my_data
);
```

| status |
| --- |
| Statement executed successfully. |

now we can use that value:

```
select $AVG_VAL * 2;
```

| $AVG_VAL * 2 |
| --- |
| 35.666666 |

But the next query:

```
SELECT VALUE + $AVG_VAL
FROM my_data
```

> 002003 (42S02): SQL compilation error:
>
> Object 'MY_DATA' does not exist or not authorized.

has no CTE called `my_data`, so that need to be insert:

```
with my_data(Key,Index,Value) as (
        select * from values
            (1, 3, 10 ),
            (1, 5, 18 ),
            (1, 14, 4 ),
            (2, 2, 11 ),
            (2, 13, 24),
            (2, 29, 40)
    )
SELECT VALUE + $AVG_VAL
FROM my_data
```

If you want a table that can be "used twice" you will need an actual table, at which point I would suggest a temporary table so it only have context in this session.

Which the nature of Pankaj's answer (ether via a permanent or temp table)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I want to create a temp table in snowflake and my cte table my_data is gotten after preprocessing a permanent table such as "SELECT key, index, value FROM perm_data", then how do I do that? I know how to create a temporary table from scratch, not by preprocessing another table. Is it just: "Create temp table my_data as (SELECT key, index, value FROM perm_data)"?

Comment: And if I close the worksheet in snowflake web interface, then the temp table will be deleted because the session ended, right? And what if I ran the code, the temp table was created, then I fixed my code and now I want to rerun the code again. Will I face an error that says "my_data table already exists" since I created it in the previous run? If this is the case, then how can I avoid this problem? Should I start a new session? Sorry for the several questions, I just wanna learn more. Thanks.

Comment: yes, if the session end, the table is gone, if the table needs rebuilding `CREATE OR REPLACE` it. The offer for the temp table is not a solves all problems, but it seems you are thinking about a concept, and want to "use a thing" more than once, while that matches the words of a Common Table Expression, that is not the scope of how they work.

Comment: what if I ran the code, the temp table was created, then I fixed my code and now I want to rerun the code again. Will I face an error that says "my_data table already exists" since I created it in the previous run? If this is the case, then how can I restart the session every time I rerun the code in snowflake without closing the worksheet?

Comment: the comments is not the place to teach "how/why to use temp tables" just make a real table, and replace it when you want to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as in  -

```
select * from d2;
+-----+-----+
| ID1 | ID2 |
|-----+-----|
|   1 |   2 |
| 100 |   2 |
|   3 |   4 |
| 300 |   4 |
+-----+-----+
```

Setting variable -

```
set (var1) = (select sum(id2) from d2);
+----------------------------------+
| status                           |
|----------------------------------|
| Statement executed successfully. |
+----------------------------------+
```

Using variable -

```
select id1+$var1 from d2;
+-----------+
| ID1+$VAR1 |
|-----------|
|        13 |
|       112 |
|        15 |
|       312 |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternatvie approach is to simply use windowed AVG function:

```
with my_data(Key,Index,Value) as (
    -- data table as cte
    select * from values
        (1, 3, 10),
        (1, 5, 18),
        (1, 14, 4),
        (2, 2, 11),
        (2, 13, 24),
        (2, 29, 40)
)
SELECT VALUE, AVG(VALUE) OVER(),
      VALUE + AVG(VALUE) OVER()
FROM my_data;
```

Output:

[image]

`OVER()` means that the window used to compute average spans over all rows.